# How to get LabelActionData of a Label

Tags: microsoft-information-protection

I'm trying to see how to get Labels that does not have any action data for encryption. I see in the SDK it lists LabelActionData as a class, but I can't see anything in the Labels themselves that lets me get the ActionData of that label. Is there anyway to get it via fileEngine to get the labelActionData of each label after getting all the labels with listLabels?